# Is there a way to make a key or legend for a heat map with dc.js?

Tags: dc.js

I made a heat map with dc.js and I was wondering if there is a key or a legend function for heat maps in dc.js. I have searched the internet and can't seem to find a built in way of doing it, so has anyone else tackled this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced this same task and what I did is I made a second heat map that is one row long from the min value to the max value.

```
var range = maxValue - minValue;

var heatArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  heatArr.push({
    val: minValue + i / 23 * rangeValue,
    index: i
  });
}

var ndx = crossfilter(heatArr);

var keyHeatmap = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
  return [d.index, 1];
});

var keyHeatmapGroup = keyHeatmap.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  return d.val;
});

var heatmapChart = dc.heatMap("#heatmapKey");

var heatColorMapping = function(d) {
  return d3.scale.linear().domain([minValue, maxValue]).range(["blue", "red"])(d);
};

heatColorMapping.domain = function() {
  return [minValue, maxValue];
};

heatmapChart.width(400)
        .height(80)
        .dimension(keyHeatmap)
        .group(keyHeatmapGroup)
        .colorAccessor(function(d) {
          return d.value;
        })
        .keyAccessor(function(d) { return d.key[0]; })
        .valueAccessor(function(d) { return d.key[1]; })
        .colsLabel(function(d){
          return heatArr[d].val.toFixed(0);
        })
        .rowsLabel(function(d) {
          return "Key";
        })
        .transitionDuration(0)
        .colors(heatColorMapping1)
        .calculateColorDomain();

heatmapChart.xBorderRadius(0);
heatmapChart.yBorderRadius(0);
```

minValue and maxValue were found in my original heat map. My final result looked like this:

[image]

Comment: That is a creative solution.

Comment: This is simple and neat solution. It would be wonderful to see this on jsfiddle.